# Why do these same pieces of code produce different outputs?

Tags: html, joomla

For my job, we have a developer website, and a live website; and anytime I want to make any type of edit or change, I am to test it on the developer site and then put it on the live site. On the homepages for both websites, everything looks pretty similar except for the fact that on the live site, in the second column of articles i put buttons at the bottom of them, and they are all supposed to be lined up horizontally, but they aren't on the live site, only the dev site. It's one specific article that the button is unaligned on, and here are the codes for both of them:

DEV:

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
<a href="/index.php/media-center/articles"><img alt="" src="images/yootheme/head_lead4.jpg" /></a></div>
```

**[News & Events](/index.php/media-center/articles)**

- [Organic CM: Activity Types](/index.php/media-center/articles/185-activity-types)
- [Continuous Integration from a Process Engineering Perspective](/index.php/media-center/articles/183-processengineeringperspective)
- [CMI Feature Videos: An Introduction](/index.php/media-center/videos)
- [CMI Launches its Software Development Center of Excellence in Bangalore, India](/index.php/media-center/articles/218-cmi-launches-its-software-development-center-of-excellence-in-bangalore-india)

Live:

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
<a href="/index.php/media-center/articles"><img alt="" src="images/yootheme/head_lead4.jpg" /></a></div>
```

**[News & Events](/index.php/media-center/articles)**

- [Organic CM: Activity Types](/index.php/media-center/articles/185-activity-types)
- [Continuous Integration from a Process Engineering Perspective](/index.php/media-center/articles/183-processengineeringperspective)
- [CMI Feature Videos: An Introduction](/index.php/media-center/videos)
- [CMI Launches its Software Development Center of Excellence in Bangalore, India](/index.php/media-center/articles/218-cmi-launches-its-software-development-center-of-excellence-in-bangalore-india)

The two codes look exactly the same to me....Also, here is the live site link [Live Site](http://www.cmi.com)

I cannot give the link for the dev site for security reasons, but just assume that the buttons on the bottom are aligned.

Comment: Check that you (or someone else) didn't make a css change in the dev site that didn't get copied over

Comment: The markup is different in that column vs. the one next to it.  In the middle one, the `article` contains a `div` which contains 4 `p`s.  In the right one, the `article` contains a `div` which contains: `div`, `p`, `ul`, `p`.  There could be some inherited styling based on the nested structure of the tags that isn't being applied as a result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting a height to each of the div's, like this:

```
<div style="text-align:center; height:315px;">
```

Adjust the height as you need, thats just a guess by eye :)

That should work.

If it doesn't add margin to the top of the button like so:

```
<div style="text-align:center; margin-top:5px;">
```

Hope that helped :)

Comment: Thank you so much! I used the <P style= "text-align:center; margin-top:27px;"></p>  code and it worked like a charm; I appreciate your answer and your time taken to help me out!